# is there any VS Code extension to preview fonts in CSS?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, font

Is there any extension (VS CODE) that previews the font-family in CSS, similar to word where we can visualize the font without select it, just by opening the font box?

Comment: [CSS Preview](https://github.com/sandorengholm/csspreview) seems like what you need, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: didn't work either...

Answer (score 1):

Personally I am using plugin called **SVG Font Previewer**. It is built for viewing `SVG` files, especially `SVG font` files.

It is working very well - more information on the official plugin page:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkokhelox.svg-font-previewer